# How to set quantity of items to buy in Paypal Orders API?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I can create a `PayPal Order` inside my `Laravel Controller` like so:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $provider = \PayPal::setProvider();
    $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken();
    $provider->setAccessToken($token);

    $price = '2';
    $currency = '';

    $order = $provider->createOrder([
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'purchase_units' => [
            [
                'amount' => [
                    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                    'value' => $price
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    return response()->json($order);
}
```

this works on its own but when I try to add a `quantity` property (quantity of the same item to be bought):

```
$provider = \PayPal::setProvider();
$provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
$token = $provider->getAccessToken();
$provider->setAccessToken($token);

$price = '2';
$currency = '';

$order = $provider->createOrder([
    'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
    'purchase_units' => [
        [
            'amount' => [
                'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                'value' => $price,
                'item_total' => [
                    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                    'value' => '7.50'
                ]
            ],
            'items' => [
                'name' => 'photo',
                'quantity' => '5',
                'unit_amount' => [
                    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                    'value' => '1.50'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

return response()->json($order);
```

I'm getting a warning:

```
click_initiate_payment_reject {err: 'Error: Expected an order id to be passed\n    at ht…ng=card,giropay,sepa,sofort&currency=EUR:2:14811)', timestamp: '1657705690794', referer: 'www.sandbox.paypal.com', sdkCorrelationID: 'f857450e442be', sessionID: 'uid_c2bc52c0a2_mdk6mzg6mta', …}
```

and this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?
```

The `order id` is created during `createOrder()` so how can it be passed to `createOrder()`?

Am I setting the quantity incorrectly? What's the right way to do it? I really just want to send the total quantity of purchases, so that it's displayed in the paypal checkout.

Comment: Seems like you should pass an order ID...

Comment: @miken32 I think `orderID` is created during the `createOrder` function, so it can't be an input of `createOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

The Items array must be an array of item array. Just make a wrapper array

```
'items' => [
             [
                'name' => 'photo',
                'quantity' => '5',
                'unit_amount' => [
                    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                    'value' => '1.50'
                ]
              ],
            ]
```